# La phrase « Plusieurs personnes fuient ne sachant que faire » est-elle valide grammaticalement ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, participe-présent

Je voudrais savoir si cette phrase est grammaticalement juste. Un ami m'a prêté un roman qu'il est en train d'écrire et une phrase m'interpelle. La voici :

> Plusieurs personnes fuient ne sachant que faire.

Le contexte est que des personnes fuient des assaillants. Ça me semble un peu bizarre, sans que je sache pourquoi, et je ne voudrais pas faire de remarque non pertinente.

Comment: Comme disent les autres réponses, cette phrase me semble correcte, j'aurais cependant ajouté une virgule entre "fuient" et "ne", histoire de mieux séquencer la phrase.

Comment: La phrase est grammaticalement correcte mais elle a un problème de sémantique : si les gens fuient, ils ont déjà décidé que faire. La phrase réécrite en commençant par ne sachant que faire supprime ce problème de sémantique (un lien de causalité est établi entre les deux propositions).

Comment: La phrase paraît bizarre parce que le tempo est lent : telle quelle, elle ne fait pas ressentir l'urgence de fuir. Plusieurs personnes fuient, mais pas toutes, les autres restent là, à danser d'un pied sur l'autre : où est le danger ?

Comment: En gardant cet ordre, j'aurais modifié la phrase comme suit : *Plusieurs personnes fuient, ne sachant que faire **d'autre***.

Comment: Personnellement ce qui me choque le plus c'est le temps utilisé ^^ C'est tout à fait correct, mais l'écriture des romans est souvent faite au passé. Si c'est cohérent avec le reste, ça ne choquera pas.
Sinon, c'est un présent qui sonne presque comme un présent de vérité générale (c'est peut être la phrase qui veut ça). Et c'est probablement pas adapté au roman, à voir ^^
Avec un peu plus de contexte on pourrait être plus fin dans les suggestions ^^

Answer (score 4):

Cette phrase est grammaticalement correcte. Personnellement je la trouve mal écrite du point de vue stylistique, j'émets donc un jugement et tout le monde peut ne pas être d'accord, il peut y avoir de nombreux avis différents à ce sujet.

Vu le contexte donné je suppose que la phrase s'inscrit dans un récit présentant une série d'actions successives, donc avec une chronologie d'événements. Pour éviter de ralentir la lecture du récit par des allers retours de la pensée je trouve préférable dans une telle situation de conserver  l'ordre chronologique des événements dans l'écriture.

1. Les gens ne savent pas quoi faire.
2. Ils fuient.

Donc je mettrai « ne sachant que faire » en premier. Et avec une virgule entre les deux propositions.

- Ne sachant que faire, plusieurs personnes fuient.

Answer (score 4):

Cette phrase *me* semble correcte. Je pense que la phrase est composée d'une proposition subordonnée.

*Après plus ample réflexion, je pense qu'il faut employer un complément d'objet après le verbe fuire*.

> Des personnes **fuient** les assaillants, *ne sachant que faire*.

« ne sachant que faire » pourrait être perçue comme une proposition participiale ayant une fonction de complément circonstanciel de but : les personnes ne savent pas que faire pour contrer les assaillants ou pour se protéger.  Cette construction pourrait aussi être perçue comme une locution ayant une fonction adjectivale : les personnes sont démunies ou désorientées par rapport à ce qui leur arrivent ; leur état étant la conséquence de ce qui se produit.

Au niveau du style, je pense au contraire que la position en fin de phrase de la proposition participiale et l'usage du participe présent dynamise le récit. On peut s'imaginer des gens paniqués courant en tous sens ou des groupes de personnes fuyant le danger, démunis.

---

<sub>REF. [Trésor informatisé de la langue française](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir)</sub>
<sub>1. *Ne savoir que faire, quoi faire.* Être indécis; être désemparé.</sub>
<sub>2. *Ne savoir que faire, qu'inventer pour + inf.* Avoir déployé toutes les ressources pour réussir une entreprise délicate.</sub>

Comment: Je ne comprends pas tout : "*semble équivaloir à... de conséquence*". (à cause de sa position ?) Suivi immédiatement de "Les personnes fuient parce que" (manquerait : *Alors que* ?)

Comment: Je veux bien à la limite que la proposition *"semble une sc de conséquence"* en raison de sa position maintenant on ne peut pas la dire ainsi car, comme vous le dites ensuite, elle exprime la **cause**. C'est le pourquoi de ma suggestion du **Alors que** entre votre hypothèse et  l'explication.

Comment: J'admets très volontiers n'avoir pas compris. Maintenant... Ainsi que vous l'expliquez vous-même : le *ne sachant que faire* exprime bien la **cause** de la fuite, une circonstance causale, et en aucun cas sa conséquence. Je fuis **parce que** je ne sais pas quoi faire d'autre. Et non pas Je ne sais pas quoi faire d'autre parce que je fuis.